# ansible include_vars file with name of os and version

Tags: ansible

I now have a multiple roles to load the some os-version specific variables:

```
- name: load CentOS 7 variable
  include_vars: "CentOS-7.yml"
  when:
    - ansible_facts['distribution'] == "CentOS"
    - ansible_facts['distribution_major_version'] == "7"

- name: load Ubuntu 18 variables
  include_vars: "Ubuntu-18.yml"
  when:
    - ansible_facts['distribution'] == "Ubuntu"
    - ansible_facts['distribution_major_version'] == "18"
```

I would like to have a generic role; how could I load the vars file with the name of the OS and version? Something like

```
- name: load OS specific variables
  include_vars: "{{distribution}}-{{distribution_major_version}}.yml"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
- name: load OS specific variables
  include_vars: "{{ ansible_distribution }}-{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}.yml"
```

This is the same as using the `ansible_facts` hash but more compact. Here is the equivalent:

```
- name: load OS specific variables
  include_vars: "{{ ansible_facts['distribution'] }}-{{ ansible_facts['distribution_major_version'] }}.yml"
```

Note that you can be more specific loading vars with a [`first_found` query](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#selecting-files-and-templates-based-on-variables) if needed. Example:

```
- name: look for the most specific os vars and drop to default
  include_vars: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ query('first_found', { 'files': myfiles, 'paths': mypaths }) }}"
  vars:
    myfiles:
      - "{{ ansible_distribution }}-{{ ansible_distribution_version }}.yml"
      - "{{ ansible_distribution }}-{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}.yml"
      - "{{ ansible_distribution }}.yml"
      - "default.yml"
    mypaths:
      - vars
      - someother/vars/dir
```